# How do I get pandas.read_csv to interpret a null entry as integer 0?

Tags: pandas, csv

With pandas.read_csv, I am reading a CSV which includes null entries, e.g.,

```
col1,col2,col3
2,3,4
8,,9
```

read_csv interprets the null entry as a float nan (since there is no int nan), so the column is being read as float64. If I try to force the column to be read as an integer, I get an error:

```
pd.read_csv(FILE, dtype = {'col2': int})
=> ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 1
```

Should I read the data as float or string and convert afterwards? Or is there some way to specify that a null entry in an int column should be interpreted as zero?

Also, is there some way to turn on more detailed error reporting? I am new to pandas and it would have been helpful to know that the error was in row 1 (obviously my real data was much bigger).

Comment: Try replacing the dtype with ``dtype={"col2": "Int64"}``. You can use ``fillna`` after to replace the null values with 0. Not so sure about detailed reporting though. An alternative to reading the data would be datatatable's [fread](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/fread.html), which can give you some log output while reading in the data. Not sure if that is what you want. So something like this : ```dt.fread(
    """col1,col2,col3
2,3,4
8,,9""",
    verbose=True,
)```  you can always convert back to pandas